# Replacing switch with polymorphic class

Tags: java, polymorphism

I used a switch statement to sort a PriorityQueue which stores objects of Event type.

```
  private PriorityQueue<Event> events = new PriorityQueue<Event>();
```

Now, events can be one of two states, `ARRIVAL` or `DONE`.

```
class Event implements Comparable<Event> {
  private int eventType;

  public Event(int type) {
    this.eventType = type;
}
```

Events are generated as such.

```
Event newArrival = new Event(1) // or 2
this.events.add(newArrival);
```

Where the integer `1` represents `ARRIVAL`, and `2` represents `DONE`.

I have the following switch statement that performs certain actions based on what event type the Event object is.

```
//Event is polled out and passed to simulateEvent.
public void simulateEvent(Event e) {
    switch (e.getEventType()) {
      case 1:
        Event e = new Event(2) // If event is "1", queue a new "2", done event.
        events.add(e);
        ... 
      case 2:
        ...
      default:
        System.err.printf("Unknown event type %d\n", e.getEventType());
  }
```

Now I was told by my professor I could use to polymorphism to achieve this instead i.e.

```
abstract class Event implements Comparable<Event>{
}

class ArrivalEvent extends Event implements Comparable<Event>{

}

class DoneEvent extends Event implements Comparable<Event>{

}
```

So far, all the polymorphic examples I've seen has been talking about using the parent class to create an array hence reducing the need to create individual child objects.

However, I am uncertain on how I would implement a similar, polymorphic style, event that my simulator can test. Considering that the event type is set in the constructor, how would I got about adapting my code such that I can remove the switch statement?

Comment: You would add an abstract `simulate()` method in Event, and implement it differently in ArrivalEvent and in DoneEvent. And you would call event.simulate() instead of simulate(event).

Comment: sidenote: You should use enum fields for `ARRIVAL` and `DONE` instead of integer numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Event itself should contain the code that is to be executed within the switch, so basically

```
public abstract class Event {
    public abstract void execute();
}
```

so in your event handler, you can simplify to

```
public void simulateEvent(Event e) {
    e.execute();
}
```

and the implementation goes into the concrete classes like this:

```
public class ArrivalEvent implements Event {
    public void execute() {
        arrivals.add(new DoneEvent());
    }
}
```

As a side note, I'd change EventType to be an enum:

```
public enum EventType {
     ARRIVAL, DONE;
}
```

that gets rid of the 1 for ARRIVAL and 2 for DONE.
If you event need the event type anymore after the above change.

Comment: Sorry, but is it true to say then, if i needed to know the current Event's type before generating a new Arrival/Done event, I would still have to check for a n Event's type before calling on that particular class's execute() method?

Comment: @carrein not sure what you mean... If die as I describe, you always know the type of the current event because you're in the code of a certain class representing the event type. In your question, you only posted what your arrival event did, so that's what I did too.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.

```
   public interface Event extends Comparable<Event>{
       void updateEvents(PriorityQueue events);
   }

   public class ArrivalEvent implements Event{

     public void updateEvents(PriorityQueue events) {
         events.add(DoneEvent.getInstance());
     }

     public static Event getInstance() {
         return new ArrivalEvent();
     }

   }

   public class DoneEvent implements Event {

     public void updateEvents(PriorityQueue events) {
         // Whatever is needed
     }

     public static Event getInstance() {
         return new DoneEvent();
     }

   }

   public void simulateEvent(Event e) {
       e.updateEvents(events);    
   }
```

Comment: Would e.updateEvents(events), calls whichever class, ARRIVAL/DONE, based on the arguments given to it i.e. 'events'?